# Qt : event invisible widget?

Tags: qt, events, qwidget, qtablewidget

For some reasons, I need to draw a widget onto one another.
The structure is the following (see the image) :

- I have an original QTableWigetItem
- On the QTableWigetItem, I create a QWidget at the foreground with the same geometry
- This QWidget contains a QBoxLayout
- This QBoxLayout contains a QPixmap and a QComboBox
  [image]

I want to do the following things :
The QWidget is just a "container" for my QBoxLayout and I would like to set him completely "invisible" for the user. If the user click or move at the position of the widget, I want the event of the QTableWigetItem in the background to be trigerred. But the problem is that I want the QPixmap and the QComboBox to be at the foreground, visible and "normal". For me it's just a trick to be able to put children widgets in a QTableWidget of a HeaderView.

How to make the QWidget "completely invisible" (from the event/signals point of view) ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `QWidget::setWindowOpacity(0)`